# Prism WPF Navigation with parameter from Infrastructure

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm trying to navigate from an Infrastructure solution with parameter as model, and set `DataContext` also.

**Issue:** Even though i'm setting the different datacontext, but always sets the first one which was loaded at first.

```
UserControl _containerLoanView;
NavigationParameters navParameter = new NavigationParameters();
LoanModel loanModel = new LoanModel();
switch (loanType)
{
    case "Weekly Loan":

        _containerLoanView = _container.Resolve(typeof(object), Constants.LoanView) as UserControl;
        _containerLoanView.DataContext = new WeekLoanVeiwModel();                                        
        navParameter.Add("WeeklyLoanVM", loanModel);
        if (_regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ManagementRegion].GetView(Constants.WeeklyLoanView) == null)
        {
            _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ManagementRegion].Add(_containerLoanView, Constants.WeeklyLoanView);
        }
        break;
    case "Daily Loan":
        _containerLoanView = _container.Resolve(typeof(object), Constants.LoanView) as UserControl;
        _containerLoanView.DataContext = new DailyLoanViewModel();
        navParameter.Add("DailyLoanVM", loanModel);
        if (_regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ManagementRegion].GetView(Constants.DailyLoanView) == null)
        {
            _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ManagementRegion].Add(_containerLoanView, Constants.DailyLoanView);
        }
        break;
}

_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ManagementRegion, new Uri(Constants.LoanViewLocation, UriKind.Relative), navParameter);
```

Comment: Your `RequestNavigate` call is only going to one place; to whatever value is in the the `Constants.LoanViewLocation` property. Should this change depending on the `loanType`?

Comment: @Richards, One single view but datacontext(viewmodel) should change depends on loan type

Comment: Have you tried this without the call to `RequestNavigate`? Adding the view to the region *should* be enough to activate the view.

Comment: Without RequestNavigate, the Loanview is not loading into the mainview region.

Comment: Why two different view models? Can't you use one view model and pass the parameters that differentiate your current view models as parameter? If those two can share a common view, they most likely shouldn't be two differnet view models. Anyway, do either `Regions[].Add` or `RequestNavigate`... but referencing and even creating the view from a view model, really feels wrong. Not to speak of using the container directly.